# Spring Boot - Spring Data giving Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor' error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I have a spring boot spring data application. This was working fine when my repository extended CrudRepository. To get dynamic querying, I extended QueryByExampleExecutor. After extending QueryByExampleExecutor, and run the mvn spring-boot:run, I am getting the below error:

```
 ***An exception occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeProfileRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)***
```

Repository Class:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface EmployeeProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeProfile, Long>, QueryByExampleExecutor<EmployeeProfile> {

}
```

Service Class:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeProfileService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeProfileRepository empProfileRepository;

    public List<EmployeeProfile> searchEmployees(Long id, String firstName, String lastName) {

        List<EmployeeProfile> employees = new ArrayList<>();

        EmployeeProfile emp = new EmployeeProfile();
        emp.setId(id);
        emp.setFirstName(firstName);
        emp.setLastName(lastName);
        Example<EmployeeProfile> example = Example.of(emp);

        Iterable<EmployeeProfile> iterable = empProfileRepository.findAll(example);
        iterable.forEach(employees::add);

        return employees;
    }

}
```

Application class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.employee.dao")
@ComponentScan("com.employee")
@EntityScan("com.employee.dto")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```